# Assign value of a class to another class

Tags: ruby

I was wonder if it is possible to assign value of a class to another class like this example.

```
class Test1
  attr_accessor :num1, :num2
  def initialize
    @num1 = num1
    @num2 = num2
  end
end

class Test2
  attr_accessor :number1, :number2
  def initialize
    @number1 = number1
    @number2 = number2
  end
end

num = Test1.new(1, 2)
number = Test2.new(11, num)

number.number2 = temp
puts temp.num2
```

I get an "`initialize': wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 0) (ArgumentError)" message. So i don't know if i get error in the code or it is not possible to assign class to another class this way.

Comment: Take a closer look at the error message. The backtrace (line number) will indicate that it already fails at `num = Test1.new(1, 2)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define your `initialize` method to take `num1` and `num2`, and `number1` and `number2` as arguments. Otherwise it is assigning the return value of the accessor methods to the instance variables, and those methods are just returning `nil`.

```
class Test1
  attr_accessor :num1, :num2
  def initialize(num1, num2)
    @num1 = num1
    @num2 = num2
  end
end

class Test2
  attr_accessor :number1, :number2
  def initialize(number1, number2)
    @number1 = number1
    @number2 = number2
  end
end
```

You will still get an error resulting from `temp` not being defined before you attempt to use it.